# Is it possible to lazy evaluate intermediate elements in a take() over a Stream? (see explanation)

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I have an infinite Stream and need to "pull" from it until some element, naturally.
This is the first step.
But only part of the "pulled" elements will be used in the second step, e.g. only the even
elements.
Is it possible to avoid processing the odd elements by means of lazyness?

The better way to explain what I am asking is showing the code:

```
  Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).
  Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
  Type :help for more information.

  scala> var n=0; def numbers:Stream[Int] = {n += 1; println("n= " + n); n #:: numbers}
  n: Int = 0
  numbers: Stream[Int]

  scala> numbers.map{z => println("z^2= " + z*z) ; z*z}.take(10)(2)
  n= 1
  z^2= 1
  n= 2
  z^2= 4
  n= 3
  z^2= 9
  res0: Int = 9

  scala> var n=0; def numbers:Stream[Int] = {n += 1; println("n= " + n); n #:: numbers}
  n: Int = 0
  numbers: Stream[Int]

  scala> numbers.map{lazy z => println("z^2= " + z*z) ; z}.take(10)(2)
  <console>:1: error: lazy not allowed here. Only vals can be lazy
  numbers.map{lazy z => println("z^2= " + z*z) ; z*z}.take(10)(2)
  ^

  scala>
```

Since the result of `take(10)(2)` is `res0: Int = 9`, only the `z^2= 9` calculation is really needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to defer the calculation of `z^2` (the `map` operation), a `view` should suffice:

```
object Worksheet {
  var n = 0                                   //> n  : Int = 0
  def numbers: Stream[Int] = { n += 1; println("n= " + n); n #:: numbers }
                                              //> numbers: => Stream[Int]

  numbers.view.map { z => println("z^2= " + z * z); z }.take(10)(2)
                                              //> n= 1
                                              //| n= 2
                                              //| n= 3
                                              //| z^2= 9
                                              //| res0: Int = 3
}
```

If you also want to defer the generation of the numbers in the stream until they are needed, you can do so manually:

```
object sheet {
  var n = 0                                   //> n  : Int = 0
  def numbers: Stream[() => Int] = (() => { n += 1; println("n= " + n); n }) #:: numbers
                                              //> numbers: => Stream[() => Int]

  numbers.view.map { z => val x = z(); println("z^2= " + x * x); x }.take(10)(2)
                                              //> n= 1
                                              //| z^2= 1
                                              //| res0: Int = 1
}
```

The issue here seems to be that the streams in the Scala library are not lazy in their head. I wouldn't be surprised if the Scalaz library had something like that already.

Comment: I will still think about it, but shouldn't res0 be 9?

Comment: I expanded my answer to show an example of how to defer only the `map` operation. In the second example, the generation is also deferred to the point where the number is needed. Since the generating "function" has a side-effect (eeek), you can observe that only one number is generated (even though it is actually the third in the stream).

Comment: It seems that [EphemeralStream](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.0-1-6.0/doc.sxr/scalaz/EphemeralStream.scala.html) in Scalaz is lazy both in `tail` and `head`.

Comment: @asflierl It seems to be exactly what I needed. I edited the operation to `x*x` in both question and answer for a more meaningful function result - for better clarity.

Comment: The first code is enough, actually obligatory, to me because my Stream is really a "data stream" and all elements must be consumed, despite the laziness in the post processing. tnx.